# Change markup of inserted image on CKEditor 4.x

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to change the markup of inserted images on CKEditor 4.x.
My images must have a description and the name of it's author near the image.

I already have a way of obtaining the image info and after a little digging, I got this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
            // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
            var dialogName = ev.data.name;
            var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
            var editor = ev.editor;

            // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
            // interested in (the 'image' dialog). This dialog name found using DevTools plugin
            if (dialogName == 'image') {
                // Remove the 'Advanced' tabs from the 'Image' dialog.
                dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');

                // Get a reference to the 'Image Info' tab.
                var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

                // Remove unnecessary widgets/elements from the 'Image Info' tab.        
                infoTab.remove('txtAlt');
                infoTab.remove('txtHSpace');
                infoTab.remove('txtVSpace');
                infoTab.remove('txtBorder');
                dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e) {
                    var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;
                    var width = e.sender.originalElement.$.width;
                    var height = e.sender.originalElement.$.height;
                    var jqxhr = $.getJSON('data.json');
                    jqxhr.done(function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        console.log(data);
                        var imgHtml = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(
                        '<div class="figure">' +
                        '<img src="' + imageSrcUrl + '" alt="' + data.description + '"' +
                            'width="' + width + '"' + 'height="' + height + '"' +'/>' +
                        '<div class="figcaption">' + data.description + '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                        editor.insertElement(imgHtml);
                    });
                };
            }
        });
```

This correctly inserts the image the way I want, but there is a problem: if I try editing the image, when I click 'Ok' button, only the tag `img` is replaced, and then I get a markup like this:

```
<div class="figure">
<div class="figure"><img alt="foo" src="xxxxxxxxx"/>
<div class="figcaption">foo</div>
</div>

<div class="figcaption">foo</div>
</div>
```

So, is it possible to me to change the "base markup" of the image, so when I alter the image, all the elements are changed?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to to isn't easy. You may want to wait for the [Widgets feature](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9764) coming soon to the editor (4.3) which would solve your issue.